# Rails help message messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used to be able to type `rails generate` or `rails generate model` to
get help information for different rails command lines, for some
unknown reason, now if I type `rails generate` or `rails generate model`,
it always show me the help message for `rails new`, what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens if you are not in a rails path, so make sure your curfrent terminal / cmd is in a directory with a rails app you can change dirfectory with `cd "/putdirectoryhere"`